# YSlow reports "no expire date" and "not cacheable"

Tags: caching, yslow

I have a wep page: http://uranussup.info. I ran a yslow test. There are a lot of requests (20) and it says "Content is not cacheable" and "No expire date." How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

### Short version

You need to configure your server so that it serves your website's content with different  [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

### Long version

From the Yahoo! [*Best Practices for Speeding up Your Web Site*](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires):

> #### Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header
>
> There are two aspects to this rule:
>
> - For static components: implement "Never expire" policy by setting far
>     future `Expires` header
> - For dynamic components: use an appropriate `Cache-Control` header to
>     help the browser with conditional
>     requests
>
> Web page designs are getting richer
>   and richer, which means more scripts,
>   stylesheets, images, and Flash in the
>   page. A first-time visitor to your
>   page may have to make several HTTP
>   requests, but by using the Expires
>   header you make those components
>   cacheable. This avoids unnecessary
>   HTTP requests on subsequent page
>   views. Expires headers are most often
>   used with images, but they should be
>   used on *all* components including
>   scripts, stylesheets, and Flash
>   components.
>
> Browsers (and proxies) use a cache to
>   reduce the number and size of HTTP
>   requests, making web pages load
>   faster. A web server uses the Expires
>   header in the HTTP response to tell
>   the client how long a component can be
>   cached. This is a far future Expires
>   header, telling the browser that this
>   response won't be stale until April
>   15, 2010.
>
> ```
> Expires: Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT
> ```
>
> If your server is Apache, use the
>   ExpiresDefault directive to set an
>   expiration date relative to the
>   current date. This example of the
>   ExpiresDefault directive sets the
>   Expires date 10 years out from the
>   time of the request.
>
> ```
> ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
> ```
>
> Keep in mind, if you use a far future
>   Expires header you have to change the
>   component's filename whenever the
>   component changes. At Yahoo! we often
>   make this step part of the build
>   process: a version number is embedded
>   in the component's filename, for
>   example, yahoo_2.0.6.js.
>
> Using a far future Expires header
>   affects page views only after a user
>   has already visited your site. It has
>   no effect on the number of HTTP
>   requests when a user visits your site
>   for the first time and the browser's
>   cache is empty. Therefore the impact
>   of this performance improvement
>   depends on how often users hit your
>   pages with a primed cache. (A "primed
>   cache" already contains all of the
>   components in the page.) We measured
>   this at Yahoo! and found the number of
>   page views with a primed cache is
>   75-85%. By using a far future Expires
>   header, you increase the number of
>   components that are cached by the
>   browser and re-used on subsequent page
>   views without sending a single byte
>   over the user's Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

**This should do it, but not sure if it's "mod_expires.c" or "mod_expires.so" - neither is working for me at the moment.**

```
<IfModule mod_expires.so>
  ExpiresActive On 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 4 hours"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript-x "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-ico "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType application/ico "access plus 12 month"
</IfModule>
```